# Is there a way to open a file for the user to read?

Tags: python-3.x

I know it's possible for you to open a file and edit it, but is it possible for a python program to open a file so the user can read it? I'm trying to find a way to open up .txt file so the user can see what was written on it.

Comment: this needs more info.  where's the file (on the server)?  where's the user (browser? something else?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print to terminal/command line you could just do something like this.

```
with open("line_file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines():
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

But make a habit of reading files line by line and stripping it as well.

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    line=f.readline()
    while line:
        print(line.strip())
        line=f.readline()
```